# Python regular expression for multiline JSON

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a JSON document that I need to parse with Regexp for some reasons outside of my control.

I have the following document:

```
{
  "overall_status_ok" : true,
  "reply_host" : "ip-10-182-81-74.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "cached_ts" : "2019-09-02T14:44:53+0000",
  "status" : "UP",
  "ssh" : {
    "status_ok" : true
  }
}
```

I came up with the following to get the status of SSH:

```
(\"overall_status_ok\".*true,)
(.*(.*\n).*)+
(\"ssh\".*(.*\n).*\"status_ok\"[\ :]+true)
```

However this does not work, causing Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your expression has been halted on https://regex101.com/

I need to check that overall_status_ok true and ssh status_ok is true. I am looking for a regexp only not Python code.

Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of `.*`

Comment: Why do you tag the question `python` when you cannot make use of it? E.g. with a proper `JSON` parser?

Comment: @Jan I guess he is at least telling us which regex engine he is using (the one from python `re` module I guess).

Comment: @OP What are you trying to achieve with `(.*(.*\n).*)+` ? Also it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, try to give an example output.

Comment: i need to check if  "overall_status_ok" : true and  "ssh" -> "status_ok" : true

Comment: @jan exactly as Valentin says.  Regexp engines are different this must run with Python's

Comment: Hm, if the Python regex module is used, than I'd expect there is also the Python json module included. Otherwise, this is a nearly ancient Python version. Are you really sure you can't use the built-in json module?

Comment: The `(.*(.*\n).*)+` is killing it. `(?s)(\"overall_status_ok\"[\s:]+true,)\s*(.*?)\s*(\"ssh\".*?\"status_ok\"[\s:]+true)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Twx03Z/1)) is a bit better, but far from perfect.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew put it in an answer it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually always use a JSON parser to parse JSON data.

As some workaround, you may try to fix the regex to get rid of the `(.*(.*\n).*)+` parts that lead to catastrophic backtracking as this pattern creates too many possibilities to match a string:

```
(?s)(\"overall_status_ok\"[\s:]+true,)\s*(.*?)\s*(\"ssh\".*?\"status_ok\"[\s:]+true)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Twx03Z/1).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `re.DOTALL` modifier inline version
- `(\"overall_status_ok\"[\s:]+true,)` - Group 1: `"overall_status_ok"` string, 1+ whitespaces and colons, and then `true,` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars but as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\"ssh\".*?\"status_ok\"[\s:]+true)` - Group 3: `"ssh"`, then any 0+ chars but as few as possible, then `"status_ok"`, 1+ whitespaces and colons, and then `true,` substring

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I agree, JSON should not be parsed by regexp, but we can't always decide which tools is used for which task.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a reason why you should want to do that
(*please don't do this in production*), but if you want to use regex, you could use regex to fish all true *status_ok entries and check, if the ones you need are included.

Working example (using Python 3.7):

```
import re

txt = """
{
  "overall_status_ok" : true,
  "reply_host" : "ip-10-182-81-74.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "cached_ts" : "2019-09-02T14:44:53+0000",
  "status" : "UP",
  "ssh" : {
    "status_ok" : true
  }
}"""

if set(m.group(1) 
       for m in re.finditer('\"(.*status_ok)\"\s*:\s*true', txt)
        ).issuperset({'overall_status_ok', 'status_ok'}):
    print('both are true')
```

Update:

A one line regex (using *txt* from above) would work like this:

```
re.search('(?s)\"(overall_status_ok)\"\s*:\s*true.*?ssh.*\"(status_ok)\"\s*:\s*true', txt)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear in the question (clarified in the comments a bit), but the asker is looking for just a python regex, *not* python code.

Comment: @glibdud - thanks for the comment, you're probably right, if the original poster updates the question or comments here, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty by any stretch of the imagination but this could work:

```
\{\s*\"overall_status_ok\"\s*:\s*true,[^}]*?\"ssh\"\s*:\s*\{\s*\"status_ok\"\s*:\s*true\s*\}\s*\}
```

https://regex101.com/r/rfyNnS/2